# El Capitan php version update using brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I just updated my Mac to OS X El Capitan 10.11.5. The stable version of php is 5.5.34. What I need something newer than that like 5.6.21.

First step I did to update my php is:

`brew install php56`. 
brew installs all the packages under this dir: `/usr/local/Cellar`.

OS X El Capitan path to php is `usr/bin`

I tried creating a symbolic link so that my php version from Cellar dir points to the one of El capitan:

```
sudo ln -sv /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

But I get this error message:

```
ln: /usr/bin/php: Operation not permitted
```

and there is nothing I can do...?

Maybe there is a another way of updating my php version on mack rather than brew and symbolic link.

Also when I want to check where is my php.ini `php --ini` i get this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
```

Comment: see @kb's answer below. You also may have to brew apache (if that is your server of choice) ... and link that to the new php, otherwise the default apache shipped with OSX will stick to the shipped php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this either at a user level with bash_profile or at a system level if you have multiple users of the machine with the paths file.

### Bash Profile Method

This is the most common method, simply add or edit an existing bash_profile file with

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the following line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Its a hierarchical order from left to right, so as you can see the it will check in `/usr/local/bin` first, then `/usr/bin` and then finally look at the original rest of the PATH variable.

### System Path File Method

Because this is a system file you need sudo power to edit this file, simply run

```
sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Then edit the file so on the first line you add `/usr/local/bin`

The final look of the file should be

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the new SIP (System Integrity Protection) in OSX you can no longer make modifications to files in the standard system directories. You need to create it in `/usr/local/bin` instead and make sure your `PATH` environment contains `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: So i need to copy the the php lib from `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.21/bin/php*`  into `usr\local\php*` and create a sub link from Cellar/../../../php* to usr/local/php* ?

Comment: @Tomazi no ! just add a line to your .bash_profile , something like `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Respawn a fresh terminal to test it, or `source .bash_profile` in a current terminal.

Comment: @Tomazi ... anything you brew, the settings are likely under /usr/local/etc ... so in your case : `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/`

Comment: yep but El Capitan reads php only from /usr/bin ......so anything I install I cant create symbolic link, and .bash_profile path does it realy change the version of php in the system or just shows but doesent really. Now it shos it loades php.ini after I went to etc and copied php.ini.default into php.ini but the syste, wont allow me edit it even if i sudo vim php.ini.

Comment: @Tomazi edit the files in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/`.